# Proof of robustness of CRD vs RBD vs RCBD

Tags: clinical-trials

I read quite a lot of papers about how RCT (random control trials) performs better than a simple naive experiment design. It's intuitive... however... i don't trust intuition and i'm looking for a textbook or paper that provide the following detailed mathematical proofs:

- That CRD (complete randomized designs) are better than naive experimental designs
- That RBD (randomized block designs) are better than CRD
- That RCBD (randomized complete block designs) are better than RBD

May some of you give me advices where i can found such proofs?

Thanks in advance for your help